# How can i point my domain to a drupal folder?

Tags: drupal, dns, directory, point

My website is www.minnerva.webege.com
My domain name is minnerva.co.nr

During drupal installation,the guide says that i need to point my domain name to the drupal folder.
Check http://drupal.org/documentation/install/beginners
Under download drupal,third subpoint.
My ISP is not allowing me to do the same so i searched for a free domain name and want to continue.

I have created a drupal folder but i dont know how to point my domain name to that folder?
Plzz help.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the name of folder at the end of domain name.

> minnerva.co.nr/drupal_folder_name